# Trigger causes an error because it is mutating the table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm writing a trigger that is supposed to add an ID of a user that has multiple bank accounts to another table once the sum of all balances he has goes over 10000 dollars. the accounts can be in different currencies so they also have to be calculated in dollars. here is the trigger:

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADD_NEW_VIP
AFTER UPDATE OF BALANCE ON BANK_ACCOUNT
for EACH row
DECLARE
    v_sum number :=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(ba.BALANCE *c.COURSE_TO_LEV)
    INTO v_sum 
    FROM bank_account ba
    INNER JOIN currency c ON ba.CURRENCY_ID=c.currency_id
    where ba.CUSTOMER_ID =  :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID;
    IF v_sum > 100000 THEN
        INSERT INTO VIP_CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID)
        VALUES (:NEW.CUSTOMER_ID);
    END IF;
END;`
```

it trows
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table STU2001321050_PROJECT.BANK_ACCOUNT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "STU2001321050_PROJECT.ADD_NEW_VIP", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'STU2001321050_PROJECT.ADD_NEW_VIP'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.

I have tried changing up the select statement but the error still appears
when I try to perform only the select for a particular id  it returns the correct sum and it returns correct. I suspect that the error comes from this line  SELECT SUM(ba.BALANCE *c.COURSE_TO_LEV) but i need to calculate the sum after its been updated.

Comment: Why do you need a trigger? Just implement this in your application rather than in the DB. A DB's purpose is to hold data, not to apply logic on it.

Comment: A view VIP_CUSTOMER could do the job and avoid another bug: as soon as a customer becomes a VIP and its balance continues to increase your trigger will try to insert it again, potentially generating a dup key error if VIP_CUSTOMER. CUSTOMER_ID has unique constraint on it. And if you create a bank_account account with an initial balance > 100000... your "update only" trigger will not be fired...

Comment: @JonasMetzler, Little bit disagree with your perception. Since now we have very strong DBs with advanced level of programming support, DBs are not limited to data storage only. We must apply most of the logics in DB side and presentation layer should only show the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `AFTER STATEMENT` trigger to only process the new balances after all modifications have occurred. If you want to only modify the changed customers then use a compound trigger.

Create a collection type to store the changed ids:

```sql
CREATE TYPE id_list
  AS TABLE OF NUMBER(10,0) -- Match data type of BANK_ACCOUNT.CUSTOMER_ID
```

Then the trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER add_new_vip
FOR UPDATE OF BALANCE ON BANK_ACCOUNT
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  ids id_list := id_list();
AFTER EACH ROW
  IS
  BEGIN
    ids.EXTEND;
    ids(ids.COUNT) := :NEW.customer_id;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;  
AFTER STATEMENT
  IS
  BEGIN
    MERGE INTO vip_customer dst
    USING (
      SELECT a.customer_id
      FROM   bank_account a
             INNER JOIN currency c
             ON a.currency_id = c.currency_id
      WHERE  a.customer_id IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(ids))
      GROUP BY a.customer_id
      HAVING SUM(a.balance *c.course_to_lev) > 100000
    ) src
    ON (dst.customer_id = src.customer_id)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (src.customer_id);
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE bank_account (account_id, customer_id, currency_id, balance) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 100000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 2, 100000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 3, 200000 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE currency (currency_id, course_to_lev) AS
SELECT 1, 0.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0.25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 0.125 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE vip_customer (customer_id) AS
SELECT customer_id FROM bank_account WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Then if you perform an `UPDATE`:

```sql
UPDATE bank_account
SET balance = 200001
WHERE account_id = 3
```

Then after the `UPDATE` the VIP customers are:

| CUSTOMER_ID |
| --- |
| 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bbBe0Erp)

Answer (score 0):

An option would be taking off the table bank_account, on which the trigger is built, from the SELECT statement such as

```
SELECT SUM( :new.balance * course_to_lev )
  INTO v_sum 
  FROM currency
 WHERE currency_id = :new.currency_id; -- assuming currency_id has unique values per each row
```

Since the table is mutating due to be referenced during the transaction.

Comment: How do you know that `currency` table contains `customer_id` column?

Comment: exactly right, I missed @Bartosz